# Issues with Xorg/Xserver

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, x-server

**Please note that this system is an UEFI boot system - /sys/firmware/efi exists**

Initially I was having issues installing i3, eventually installing many drivers until one day it randomly worked. I3 came up, and I was able to open up a terminal. Now a few days later I am trying to correctly orient my monitors, I had being using an xrandr command to do this previously, but wanted to attempt to do this in the xorg configuration file. Checking the Xorg.0.log, I realized that the server actually terminates with an error, yet I3 still starts up and I am able to use my computer normally.

A few things that I had noticed are quite weird from the log file. Its loading the nouveau module from a file which doesn't exist  in the module directory. The nouveau module is not even installed,  I have confirmed this using pacman. The log states the directory /usr/share/fonts/* doesn't exist multiple times, yet these files do exist, and I have already run mkfontdir on them. I tried to specify them as FontPaths in the config file, but it doesn't help.

Making any drastic changes to the current config file brings me back to my initial issue, but i3 won't start up, and the server ends in the same error. (The logs are exactly the same). Some changes do nothing, as if it isn't even using the config file it says it is.

I really don't understand what's going on, how am I using i3 if the server terminated. I tried many times to write the simplest conf file possible, just to get one monitor up and working to no avail. It is only this config file, generated initially using the nvidia module that allows i3 to come up, while the log states the server terminated.

- Specs:
- Kernel: 5.5.6 arch1-1
- CPU: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2950x 16- (32) @ 3.500Ghz
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 TI Rev.A
- Motherboard: Asus ROG Maximums XI Extreme
  Files
- (LOG) ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log: https://pastebin.com/WhySt7P6
- Working Xorg conf (i3 up and running but xserver terminates in the log) :https://pastebin.com/tTrLAYi7
- /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-lib-input.conf: https://pastebin.com/zK2VgzGb
- /usr/lib/module/drivers: only has modesetting_drv.so nvidia_drv.so
- /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/: Is empty
- lspci | grep VGA: VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A] (rev a1)

  I would love any sort of help to get the config running correctly, I want to orient my monitors using xorg.conf (without it terminating in the background) or using xrandr, I would like it done the right way so I can understand it.